# Configuring different releases in the same makefile

Tags: makefile

I want to generate several builds using the same make file. By several builds I mean `windows-release`, `windows-debug`, `linux-release`, `linux-debug`, and so on. My idea is to set variables according to the build I'm running, something like this:

```
windows-release:
    CC:=...
    CFLAGS:=...
    OUTDIR:=windows/release
    OBJDIR:=$(OUTDIR)/obj
    EXECUTABLE:=$(OUTDIR)/exe
    # Would call $(EXECUTABLE) here, but it's not procedural
```

And then have rules which make the actual build:

```
# This will generate a static library
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $(ARLIB) $(OBJECTS)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: src/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

I'm sorry for the incomplete example, but I don't really have a makefile yet, I'm just writing it now.

Can I do this using a makefile? Am I better of with a script instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can absolutely do this. The three things you want are [`.PHONY` targets](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets) (so make doesn't think `windows-release`, etc. are real files), [Target-specific Variable Values](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific) (so you can set variables differently depending on which target is running) and [Secondary Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion) because otherwise the evaluation of prerequisites happens outside of the target-specific context so the target-specific variables don't work).

Which combined get you something like this:

```
windows-release: CC:=...
windows-release: CFLAGS:=...
windows-release: OUTDIR:=windows/release
windows-release: OBJDIR:=$(OUTDIR)/obj
windows-release: EXECUTABLE:=$(OUTDIR)/exe

windows-debug: CC:=...
windows-debug: CFLAGS:=...
windows-debug: OUTDIR:=windows/debug
windows-debug: OBJDIR:=$(OUTDIR)/obj
windows-debug: EXECUTABLE:=$(OUTDIR)/exe

linux-release: CC:=...
linux-release: CFLAGS:=...
linux-release: OUTDIR:=linux/release
linux-release: OBJDIR:=$(OUTDIR)/obj
linux-release: EXECUTABLE:=$(OUTDIR)/bin

linux-debug: CC:=...
linux-debug: CFLAGS:=...
linux-debug: OUTDIR:=linux/debug
linux-debug: OBJDIR:=$(OUTDIR)/obj
linux-debug: EXECUTABLE:=$(OUTDIR)/bin

.SECONDEXPANSION:
windows-release windows-debug linux-release linux-debug: $$(EXECUTABLE)
```

That being said you could also just use normal global variables and conditionals for this instead:

```
ifeq (windows-release,$(filter windows-release,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
    CC:=...
    CFLAGS:=...
    OUTDIR:=windows/release
    OBJDIR:=$(OUTDIR)/obj
    EXECUTABLE:=$(OUTDIR)/exe
else ifeq (windows-debug,$(filter windows-debug,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
    CC:=...
    CFLAGS:=...
    OUTDIR:=windows/debug
    OBJDIR:=$(OUTDIR)/obj
    EXECUTABLE:=$(OUTDIR)/exe
else ifeq (linux-release,$(filter linux-release,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
    CC:=...
    CFLAGS:=...
    OUTDIR:=linux/release
    OBJDIR:=$(OUTDIR)/obj
    EXECUTABLE:=$(OUTDIR)/bin
else ifeq (linux-debug,$(filter linux-debug,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
    CC:=...
    CFLAGS:=...
    OUTDIR:=linux/debug
    OBJDIR:=$(OUTDIR)/obj
    EXECUTABLE:=$(OUTDIR)/bin
endif

windows-release windows-debug linux-release linux-debug: $(EXECUTABLE)
```

Comment: Be aware that secondary expansion is a global modification. Any targets listed after it all have it applied. This likely doesn't matter (and may, in fact, be what you want) but is something to be aware of.

Comment: Absolutely! Thanks for the heads up

Comment: Hm.. Two questions though. According to the docs: `GNU make also has the ability to enable a second expansion of the prerequisites (only) for some or all targets defined in the makefile.` I get the impression that it's not global after all, is this accurate? And does it only happen once? I mean, you have four changes on your example, but the docs talk about a second expansion

Comment: The *next* sentence explains that sentence and is what I already indicated: `In order for this second expansion to occur, the special target .SECONDEXPANSION must be defined before the first prerequisite list that makes use of this feature.` and part of the first sentence in the next paragraph furthers this explanation `all the prerequisites of the targets defined after the special target are expanded a second time`.

Comment: I didn't follow the "only happen once" and "four changes" comments/questions.

Comment: Well, never mind that part of the question, I got what you meant! I'm using the first alternative (`.SECONDEXPANSION`), but I'm getting `No rule to make target` for the `EXECUTABLE` variable, is this supposed to happen? In your example you created the dependencies (that's working nice, btw), but how can I create the rule for the actual build now ?

Comment: Wait, I think I get it now. I can't do this, can I `all: windows-release windows-debug linux-release linux-debug` ? I mean, that works if calling specifically for one of the build types, is this accurate ?

Comment: You can do that to have them all built by default **if** and **only if** they don't share any object files or executables. Nothing built using the target-specific variables can be shared between those targets. Because make will only build any target once. So any targets that are shared will be built by the first thing that requires them and will **not** be rebuilt when the next target (that uses different flags) requires it.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I concluded.. I'm trying recursion now. Thanks!